macOS command line tool for capturing the execution of an entire process tree?
I'm looking for a tool for capturing the execution of an entire process tree, like this:
# tracetree: https://github.com/luser/tracetree , linux only, sadly


$ tracetree /bin/bash -c '/bin/sleep 1; /bin/sleep 1'
16665 bash -c /bin/sleep 1; /bin/sleep 1 [2.004s]
    16666 sleep 1 [1.001s]
    16667 sleep 1 [1.000s]

Is there a tool for this?
